# How can I specify start and step size in numpy.nditer?

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following Python code which computes the first `n` [Euler Totient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) function values:

```
import numpy as np

def euler_totients(n):
    phi = np.arange(n+1)

    it = np.nditer(phi, flags=['f_index'])
    for i in it:
        if i == it.index and it.index > 1:
            for j in range(it.index, n+1, it.index):
                phi[j] -= phi[j] / it.index

    return phi
```

I would like to use `numpy.nditer` for the inner loop but it doesn't appear to allow specification of the starting point or the step size as I need for the inner loop.  The official [documentation for `numpy.nditer`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nditer.html) includes a brief description of the `itershape` parameter (which sounds promising), but it's a bit vague and doesn't include an example.

So, is there a way I can specify the starting point and step size of an `numpy.nditer` and if so, how?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  For that matter, why use `nditer` in the outer loop?

Comment: @hpaulj Primarily a learning opportunity.  But more generally, I find use of iterators are usually more performant than indexing... at least in other languages.  Is that not the case in Python?

Comment: `for i in range(...)` is the normal python iterator.  `nditer` is not better - unless you go on to compile it.

Comment: `nditer` is just a fancy way of dishing out elements from one or more arrays (such as `phi`).  The actual iteration is in the `for i in it: body` part, and most of the time is spent executing the `body` part many times.   `for i in phi` (possibly with an `enumerate` wrapper), is just as good for a simple 1d array.

Comment: The perfromant thing in `numpy` is to move the iterations into compiled code, using the array methods.  `for` loops on arrays is slower than on lists.

Comment: With that `nditer`, `index` will be the same as `i`.  With a 1d `phi`, you are just doing `for index, i in enumerate(phi): ..`. and `i==index` will always be true.

Comment: @hpaulj, Not sure on that last comment... I change the values in `phi`  within the inner loop, so `i` does not always equal `it.index` in the code above, though it may if I use `enumerate`, which would break the algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain python version is faster:

```
In [166]: def foo(n):
     ...:     phi = list(range(n+1))
     ...:     for index,i in enumerate(phi):
     ...:        if i==index and index>1:
     ...:            for j in range(index, n+1, index):
     ...:               phi[j] -= int(phi[j]/index)
     ...:     return phi
     ...: 
In [167]: foo(10)
Out[167]: [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 6, 4, 6, 4]
In [168]: timeit euler_totients(1000)
15.7 ms ± 63.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [169]: timeit foo(1000)   
637 µs ± 24.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```